# ¿Porque cuando intento aumentar mi cadena en un bucle usando realloc el depurador me dice: Segmentacion fault?

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

¿Porque el codigo me da fallo cuando aumento una cadena en una funcion, pero no cuando la aumento directamente?.
Tengo este codigo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void append(char* cadena_inicial,unsigned long int* indice,const char* sub_cadena,unsigned short sub_indice,char* salir);
int main(int argc,char** argv){
    char* texto;
    char crtr; /*crtr es un caracter.*/
    char salir='N'; /*Si esta en Y y el usuario preciona q entonces se termina el bucle*/
    const char CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[][7]={
        "&lt;",
        "&gt;\0",
        "&nbsp;",
        "&#9;",
        "<br/>"
    };
    /*Los codigo de escape son equivalente a esto en html:
    const char* CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE={
        "<",
        ">",
        "ESPACIO",
        "TAB",
        "\n"
    };
    */
    unsigned long int indice=0;
    texto=(char*)malloc(2);/*Para evitar problemas inicializamos la cadena con dos de memoria asignada*/
    printf("Escribe \\Q o \\q para terminar.\n");
    while ((crtr=getchar)!=EOF){/*Por si getchar falla*/
        switch (crtr){
            case '<':
                append(texto,&indice,CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[0],sizeof(CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[0]),&salir);
                break;
            case '>':
                append(texto,&indice,CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[1],sizeof(CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[1]),&salir);
                break;
            case ' ':
                append(texto,&indice,CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[2],sizeof(CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[2]),&salir);
                break;
            case '  ':
                append(texto,&indice,CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[3],sizeof(CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[3]),&salir);
                break;
            case '\n':
                append(texto,&indice,CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[4],sizeof(CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[4]),&salir);
                break;
            case '\\':
                if(salir!='Y')
                    salir='Y';
                else
                    salir='N';
                continue;
            default:/*Cuando la cadena pasa por aqui no hay error.*/
                if( (crtr=='Q' || crtr=='q') && salir=='Y')
                    goto end;
                else if (salir=='Y'){
                    salir='N';
                    texto=(char*)realloc(texto,(indice+1)*sizeof(char));
                    texto[indice]='\\';
                    indice++;
                }
                if ( (crtr>='a' && crtr<='z') || (crtr>='A' && crtr<='Z') ){
                    texto=(char*)realloc(texto,(indice+1)*sizeof(char));
                    texto[indice]=crtr;
                    indice++;
                }
                
        }
    }
    end:
    texto=(char*)realloc(texto,(indice+1)*sizeof(char));
    texto[indice]='\0';/*Asignamos el caracter nulo y imprimimos*/
    printf(texto);
    free(texto);/*Liberamos la memoria.*/
    getchar();/*Limpiamos un poco el buffer antes de paralizar el programa.*/
    getchar();
    return 0;/*End*/
}
void append(char* cadena_inicial,unsigned long int* indice,const char* sub_cadena,unsigned short sub_indice,char* salir){
    unsigned short i;/*Inicializamos i*/
    cadena_inicial=(char*)realloc(cadena_inicial,(*indice+sub_indice+1)*(unsigned long int)sizeof(char));/*Asignamos la memoria dinamica necesaria.*/
     if (cadena_inicial==NULL)
        exit(1);/*En caso de error terminamos.*/
    for (i=0;i < sub_indice ; i++){
    if (sub_cadena[i]=='\0')
        break;/*Si llega la caracter nulo terminamos.*/
     cadena_inicial[*indice]=sub_cadena[i];
     *indice++;
     }
     *salir=(*salir=='Y')?'N':'N';/*Por si acaso el usuario ingleso el caracter \; entonces la variable salir se pone en false en caso contrario igual.*/
}
```

El depurador al llegar a un caracter de escape me sale este `Program rececived signal SIGSEV, Segmentacion fault`, y la cadena_inicial me toma este valor: `"&\020««\rō-º«««««"`. Y solo ingleso esta entrada: `<\n`. Nota "\n" simboliza que precione intro o salto de linea.
Entonces modifico la funcion append:

```
void append(char* cadena_inicial,unsigned long int* indice,const char* sub_cadena,unsigned short sub_indice,char* salir){
    unsigned short i;/*Inicializamos i*/
    for (i=0;i < sub_indice ; i++){
    if (sub_cadena[i]=='\0')
        break;/*Si llega la caracter nulo terminamos.*/
     cadena_inicial=(char*)realloc(cadena_inicial,(*indice+1)*(unsigned long int)sizeof(char));/*Asignamos la memoria dinamica necesaria.*/
     if (cadena_inicial==NULL)
        exit(1);/*En caso de error terminamos.*/
     cadena_inicial[*indice]=sub_cadena[i];
     *indice++;
     }
     *salir=(*salir=='Y')?'N':'N';/*Por si acaso el usuario ingleso el caracter \; entonces la variable salir se pone en false en caso contrario igual.*/
}
```

El resultado es que la funcion `realloc` en vez de devolver un puntero a `char` o `char*` me devuelve `NULL`.
Entonces note que me da un error cuando la cadena pasa por otra funcion y no cuando esta directamente en `main`, he ingenie una macro:

```es
#define append(texto,indice,CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE)  for (i=0;i < sizeof(CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE) ; i++){\
     if (CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[i]=='\0') \
        break; \
     texto=(char*)realloc(texto,(indice+1)*(unsigned long int)sizeof(char)); \
     texto[indice]=CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[i]; \
     indice++; \
     } \
     salir=(salir=='Y')?'N':'N';
int main(int argc,char** argv){
char* texto;
    char crtr; /*crtr es caracter.*/
    char salir='N';
    short i=0;
    const char CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[][7]={
        "&lt;",
        "&gt;\0",
        "&nbsp;",
        "&#9;",
        "<br/>"
    };
    /*
    const char* CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE={
        "<",
        ">",
        "ESPACIO",
        "TAB",
        "\n"
    };
    */
    unsigned long int indice=0;
    texto=(char*)malloc(2);
    printf("Escribe \\Q o \\q para terminar.\n");
    while (crtr!=EOF){
        crtr=getchar();
        switch (crtr){
            case '<':
                append(texto,indice,CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[0]);
                break;
            case '>':
                append(texto,indice,CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[1]);
                break;
            case ' ':
                append(texto,indice,CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[2]);
                break;
            case '  ':
                append(texto,indice,CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[3]);
                break;
            case '\n':
                append(texto,indice,CODIGO_DE_ESCAPE[4]);
                break;
            case '\\':
                if(salir!='Y')
                    salir='Y';
                else
                    salir='N';
                continue;
            default:
                if( (crtr=='Q' || crtr=='q') && salir=='Y')
                    goto end;
                else if (salir=='Y'){
                    salir='N';
                    texto=(char*)realloc(texto,(indice+1)*sizeof(char));
                    texto[indice]='\\';
                    indice++;
                }
                if ( (crtr>='a' && crtr<='z') || (crtr>='A' && crtr<='Z') ){
                    texto=(char*)realloc(texto,(indice+1)*sizeof(char));
                    texto[indice]=crtr;
                    indice++;
                }
                
        }
    }
    end:
    texto=(char*)realloc(texto,(indice+1)*sizeof(char));
    texto[indice]='\0';
    printf(texto);
    free(texto);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Y me sale el resultado que quiero. Entonces ¿Porque el codigo me da fallo cuando aumento una cadena en una funcion, pero no cuando la aumento directamente?.

> Nota: No es por que este en depuracion, decarte esta teoria cuando lo prove directamente y window me cerro la apricacion por aceso ilegal de memoria.
> Por favor si consigue un error sintactico adviseme que es algo incomodo escribir por un dispocitivo movil.

Comment: La función `append` hace un `realloc`, pero no devuelve el nuevo puntero. El programa conserva el puntero antiguo al texto, el que ya no es válido.